# Why is volatile used in double checked locking

Tags: java, design-patterns, locking, singleton, double-checked-locking

From *Head First* design patterns book, the singleton pattern with double checked locking has been implemented as below:

```
public class Singleton {
    private volatile static Singleton instance;
    private Singleton() {}
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why `volatile` is being used. Doesn't  `volatile` usage defeat the purpose of using double checked locking i.e performance?

Comment: I thought double checked locking was broken, did somebody fix it?

Comment: For what it's worth, I found Head First design patterns to be a horrible book to learn from. As I look back on it, it makes perfect sense now that I've learned the patterns elsewhere, but to learn without knowing the patterns it really did not serve it's purpose. But it's very popular, so perhaps it was just me being dense. :-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have seen this example used as the one way in which the jvm can be trusted to do the DCL.

Comment: FWIW, on an x86 system a volatile Read-Read is supposed to result in a no-op. In fact, the only operation that requires a fence for memory consistency is a volatile Write-Read. So if you really only write the value once, then there should be minimal impact. I've not seen anyone actually benchmark this and think the result would be interesting!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan for all practical reasons, it's still broken. It's better with `volatile` (as in, "won't screw your program"), but then you don't really win much.

Comment: @TimBender Well obviously we only have an effect for write-read (if all we do is read, it's rather uninteresting which identical copy we're reading), but "Only rarely results in an error" isn't much helpful I think - actually makes it much harder to identify the problem.

Comment: @Voo, I never said "Only rarely results in an error", my point was that in theory it should only be a hit to performance shortly after initialization.

Comment: @TimBender Misunderstood you - yes I agree.

Comment: Related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18093735/465053) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12316406/465053) about why double checking is even required in first place.

Comment: check this link for why `volatile` is used in singleton: https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Answer (score 78, accepted):

A good resource for understanding why `volatile` is needed comes from the [JCIP](http://jcip.net/) book. Wikipedia has a [decent explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java) of that material as well.

The real problem is that `Thread A` may assign a memory space for `instance` before it is finished constructing `instance`. `Thread B` will see that assignment and try to use it. This results in `Thread B` failing because it is using a partially constructed version of `instance`.

Comment: OK, it looks like a new implementation of volatile fixed the memory issues with DCL. What I still don't get is the performance implication of using volatile here. From what I have read volatile is pretty much as slow as synchronized so why not just synchronize the whole getInstance() method call?

Comment: @toc777 `volatile` is slower than a usual filed. If you look for performance, go for a holder-class pattern. `volatile` is here merely to show that *there's a way* to make the broken pattern work. It's more of a coding challenge than a real problem.

Comment: @alf explains a lot, thanks. They didn't make that clear at all in the book.

Comment: @toc777, no, volatile is not just as slow as synchronized. There are musch simpler ways of implementing a Singleton: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Traditional_simple_way ... the truth though is that a Singleton is often used as global state and there is a growing movement that considers Singletons bad design. Using Dependency Injection, there would be no need for a Singleton because everything that needs it would require via a constructor or method parameter. Thus creating a large scheme of passing the reference that originates at the original creator, `main`.

Comment: @Tim well, a singleton in XML is still a singleton; understanding the runtime state of an app doesn't become easier by using DI. smaller units of code may seem simpler, at the expense of forcefully structuring all units to conform to DI idiom (a good thing some might say). The accusation against singleton is not fair, it confuses API with impl - `Foo.getInstance()` is just an expression to get a Foo somehow, it's no different from `@Inject Foo foo`; either way the site that requests a Foo is agnostic of which Foo is returned and how, either way static and runtime dependencies are the same.

Comment: @irreputable You know what is funny is that at the time we had this exchange, I had never used Spring and wasn't referring to Spring's wonky DI. The real danger with Singleton as a `static` `factory` is the temptation to call it deep inside code which should not know of the `getInstance()` method and instead demand an instance be provided.

Comment: @TimBender why volatile is NOT used in the other synchronized method implementation?  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111042/singleton-pattern-usage-of-volatile-double-checked-locking)

Comment: `The real problem is that Thread A may assign a memory space for instance before it is finished constructing instance. ` So how `volatile ` resolve this ?

Comment: @shaoyihe Nice Question. Actually the definition of volatile itself answers your question....  The value of this variable will never be cached thread-locally: all reads and writes will go straight to "main memory"; Access to the variable acts as though it is enclosed in a synchronized block, synchronized on itself.

Comment: is it possible to write a test case which will fail on x86 when variable is not `volatile`?

Comment: @javapowered You should read this : https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/

Comment: @sreekanth-karumanaghat then what is included into volatile write? Only assigning reference to variable or constructing object too? Object still can be written without construction finished

Comment: @TimBender I still didnt get. How Thread2 can see new value of `instance` varible if Thread1 is still in `synchronized` block and new value of `instance` are not flushed to main memory. I expect Thread2 will see null.

Answer (score 30):

As quoted by @irreputable, volatile is not expensive. Even if it is expensive, consistency should be given priority over performance.

There is one more clean elegant way for Lazy Singletons.

```
public final class Singleton {
    private Singleton() {}
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
    private static class LazyHolder {
        private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }
}
```

Source article : [Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) from wikipedia

> In software engineering, the Initialization on Demand Holder (design pattern) idiom is a lazy-loaded singleton. In all versions of Java, the idiom enables a safe, highly concurrent lazy initialization with good performance

Since the class does not have any `static` variables to initialize, the initialization completes trivially.

The static class definition `LazyHolder` within it is not initialized until the JVM determines that LazyHolder must be executed.

The static class `LazyHolder` is only executed when the static method `getInstance` is invoked on the class Singleton, and the first time this happens the JVM will load and initialize the `LazyHolder` class.

This solution is thread-safe without requiring special language constructs (i.e. `volatile` or `synchronized`).

Answer (score 17):

Well, there's no double-checked locking for performance. It is a *broken* pattern.

Leaving emotions aside, `volatile` is here because without it by the time second thread passes `instance == null`, first thread might not construct `new Singleton()` yet: no one promises that creation of the object *happens-before* assignment to `instance` for any thread but the one actually creating the object.

`volatile` in turn establishes *happens-before* relation between reads and writes, and fixes the broken pattern.

If you are looking for performance, use holder inner static class instead.

Comment: hi @alf，According to happens-before definition, after one thread releases the lock, another thread acquires the lock, then the latter can see the previous change.  If so, I don't think the volatile keyword is needed .  Can you explain it in more detail

Comment: But there's no lock acquisition in the case the second thread only hits the outer if, so no ordering.

Comment: Hi @alf, So are you trying to state that when the first thread creates the instance inside synchronized block then that instance might still be null to the second thread bec of cache misses and it instances it again if the instance is not volatile? can you please clarify ?

Comment: @AarishRamesh, not null; any state whatsoever. there are two operations: assigning address to the `instance` variable, and the actual creation of the object at that address. Unless there's something enforcing synchronisation, like a `volatile` access or an explicit syncronization, the second thread can get those two events out of order.

Comment: It should be noted that "Holder inner static class" only works for singletons, which is the OP example being addressed but not the only case.  Classes can have lazy-constructed instance members as well, and if you need high performance I think that double-check single-lock is the answer.  If you don't need high performance, just use a synchronized method.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you need `volatile` is because volatile has 2 semantics in Java

- variable visibility between threads
- stop re-ordering

So the problem without `volatile` in the double checked lock is that statement

`instance = new Singleton()`

have 3 main steps in bytecode which can be viewed by command `javap -c Singleton.class`

```
      17: new           #3                  // class Singleton
      20: dup
      21: invokespecial #4                  // Method "<init>":()V
```

1. Allocate memory space for the object (not initialized yet)
2. Create a variable to point to this space memory address
3. Call constructor to initialize the object

These 3 steps can be re-ordered during runtime by CPU or JVM which can be a case you will get an instance not fully initialized yet.

By having `volatile` JVM will insert `monitorenter` and `monitorexit` to avoid re-ordering as below.

```
      10: monitorenter
      11: getstatic     #2                  // Field instance:LSingleton;
      14: ifnonnull     27
      17: new           #3                  // class Singleton
      20: dup
      21: invokespecial #4                  // Method "<init>":()V
      24: putstatic     #2                  // Field instance:LSingleton;
      27: aload_0
      28: monitorexit
```

So `volative` is required for singleton.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't have it, a second thread could get into the synchronized block after the first set it to null, and your local cache would still think it was null.

The first one is not for correctness (if it were you are correct that it would be self defeating) but rather for optimization.

Comment: According to happens-before definition, after one thread releases the lock, another thread acquires the lock, then the latter can see the previous change. If so, I don't think the volatile keyword is needed . Can you explain it in more detail

Comment: @QinDongLiang If the variable is not volatile, the second thread may be using a cached value on its own stack. Being volatile forces it to go back to the source to get the proper value. Of course, it has to do this on every access and thus can have a performance hit (but let's be honest, unless it's in a super critical loop, it's probably not the worst thing in your system...)

Answer (score 2):

Declaring the variable as `volatile` guarantees that all accesses to it actually read its current value from memory.

Without `volatile`, the compiler may optimize away the memory accesses to the variable (such as keeping its value in a register), so only the first use of the variable reads the actual memory location holding the variable. This is a problem if the variable is modified by another thread between the first and second access; the first thread has only a copy of the first (pre-modified) value, so the second `if` statement tests a stale copy of the variable's value.

Comment: -1 I'm losing my reputation points today :) The _real_ reason is, there's memory cache, modeled as thread's local memory. The order in which local memory is flushed to the main one is undefined—that is, unless you have *happens-before* relations, e.g., by using `volatile`. Registers  have nothing to do with incomplete objects and DCL problem.

Comment: Your definition of `volatile` is too narrow - if that was all volatile did, double checked locking would've worked just fine in <Java5. `volatile` introduces a memory barrier making certain reordering illegal - without that even if we never read stale values from memory it'd still be unsafe. Edit: alf beat me to it, shouldn't have gotten myself some nice tea ;)

Comment: @TimBender if singleton _contains_ mutable state, flushing it has nothing to do with a reference to the singleton itself (well, there's an indirect link, as accessing a `volatlie` reference to a singleton makes your thread re-read main memory—but it's a secondary effect, not the cause of a problem:))

Comment: @alf, you're right. And actually making instance volatile doesn't help if the state inside is mutable since the flush only happens if the reference itself is changed (like making arrays/lists volatile does nothing for the contents). Chalk it up to a brain fart.

Comment: According to happens-before definition, after one thread releases the lock, another thread acquires the lock, then the latter can see the previous change. If so, I don't think the volatile keyword is needed . Can you explain it in more detail  @Tim Bender

Comment: As you may have gathered, this is a complex topic.  In fact there are several issues that must be overcome for this to work: (1) language caching of values in registers (2) language publication of new object before construction is complete (3) CPU cache seeing stale memory (4) hardware reordering of writes to shared memory.  The pattern combining both volatile and synchronized solves these issues.  See https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Answer (score 1):

A volatile read is not really expensive in itself.

You can design a test to call `getInstance()` in a tight loop, to observe the impact of a volatile read; however that test is not realistic; in such situation, programmer usually would call `getInstance()` once and cache the instance for the duration of use.

Another impl is by using a `final` field (see wikipedia). This requires an additional read, which may become more expensive than the `volatile` version. The `final` version may be faster in a tight loop, however that test is moot as previously argued.

Answer (score -2):

Double checked locking is a technique to prevent creating another instance of singleton when call to `getInstance` method is made in multithreading environment.

#### Pay attention

- Singleton instance is checked twice before initialization.
- Synchronized critical section is used only after first checking singleton instance for that reason to improve performance.
- `volatile` keyword on the declaration of the instance member. This will tell the compiler to always read from, and write to, main memory and not the CPU cache. With `volatile` variable guaranteeing happens-before relationship, all the write will happen before any read of instance variable.

#### Disadvantages

- Since it requires the `volatile` keyword to work properly, it's not compatible with Java 1.4 and lower versions. The problem is that an out-of-order write may allow the instance reference to be returned before the singleton constructor is executed.
- Performance issue because of decline cache for volatile variable.
- Singleton instance is checked two times before initialization.
- It's quite verbose and it makes the code difficult to read.

#### There are several realization of singleton pattern each one with advantages and disadvantages.

- Eager loading singleton
- Double-checked locking singleton
- Initialization-on-demand holder idiom
- The enum based singleton

Detailed description each of them is too verbose so I just put a link to a good article - [All you want to know about Singleton](http://poltora.info/blog/all-you-want-to-know-about-singleton/)