# Is this a correct use of double checked singleton?

Tags: java, static, singleton, wrapper, double-checked-locking

I am basically looking for a caching mechanism for the users of HelperWrapper.
Is this a correct use of double checked singleton?

```
final class HelperWrapper {
  private static volatile Helper helper = null;
 
  public static Helper getHelper() {
    if (helper == null) {
      synchronized (HelperWrapper.class) {
        if (helper == null) {
          helper = new Helper();
        }
      }
    }
    return helper;
  }
}
```

I know this wouldn't prevent someone from instantiating their own Helper objects, but that isn't the goal.

Additional info:

- I cannot modify the Helper class to make the constructor private. Nor do I want to.
- The requirements dictate that the helper should not be eagerly instantiated

Comment: Related reading: [Item 3 from Effective Java](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3)

Comment: I cannot modify Helper's source code, hence I cannot make its constructor private.  I'm not trying to prevent others for instantiating their own Helper.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Double checked locking is no longer broken since Java 5.

Comment: @Ares You can't modify `Helper` in any way? If that's the case, are you using a DI framework such as `Spring` or `Guice` in your applicaiton? If yes, you could enforce singleton without modifying `Helper` at all.

Comment: please look at : [enum as singlton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285520/implementing-singleton-as-enum-in-java) this is better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855700/why-is-volatile-used-in-this-example-of-double-checked-locking/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Java 5, that implementation [is safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855700/why-is-volatile-used-in-this-example-of-double-checked-locking). However, consider using an internal class instead:

```
final class HelperWrapper {
  private static final class DeferredLoader {
    public static final Helper HELPER_INSTANCE = new Helper();
  } 

  public static Helper getHelper() {
    return DeferredLoader.HELPER_INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

This both provides thread-safety and lazy initialization while leveraging the thread safety guarantees of class initialization to avoid volatile or synchronization keywords on a per call basis.

Comment: I still don't understand what's the point of a Singleton wrapper when Helper does not have a private constructor?

Comment: I cannot speak for @Ares. It could simply be that a 3rd party provides `Helper` and @Ares has found they want to consume as a singleton (perhaps for performance reasons). You are correct that they cannot prevent direct instantiation.

Comment: @bot There are a number of cases where you want a singleton instance of some type of object in a given context even though it does not have to be a singleton for the entire vm. For example, if a class can leverage an ExecutorService, it may want that to enforce a single object for that class. That does not mean that no one else in jvm should be able to produce an instance.

Comment: Do you think it would make sense to add a `static` factory method called `newInstance` to the wrapper? I know this won't change much but it will atleast give an option to rely completely on the wrapper to get hold of a `Helper`