# Double checked locking with neither volatile nor a local variable

Tags: java, multithreading, double-checked-locking

Before dismissing this, *it is possible* to implement double checked locking *without* volatile, see below. I'm suggesting a variation on this, that gets rid of the local variable.

The following is a correct implementation of double checked locking from [Shipilev](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/):

```
public class FinalWrapperFactory {
  private FinalWrapper wrapper;

  public Singleton get() {
    FinalWrapper w = wrapper;
    if (w == null) { // check 1
      synchronized(this) {
        w = wrapper;
        if (w == null) { // check2
          w = new FinalWrapper(new Singleton());
          wrapper = w;
        }
      }
    }
    return w.instance;
  }

  private static class FinalWrapper {
    public final Singleton instance;
    public FinalWrapper(Singleton instance) {
      this.instance = instance;
    }
  }
}
```

I wonder if it would be possible to get rid of the local variable `w`:

```
public class FinalWrapperFactory {
  private FinalWrapper wrapper; //same as example above

  public Singleton get() {
    if (wrapper == null) { // read 1
      synchronized(this) {
        if (wrapper == null) { // read 2
          wrapper = new FinalWrapper(new Singleton());
          return wrapper.instance; // read 3
        } else {
          return wrapper.instance; // read 4 
        }
      }
    } else {
      return wrapper.instance; // read 5 (last read). Can this be reordered?
    }
  }
}
```

In [17.4.8. Executions and Causality Requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.8) of the [JLS 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/) it is written:

> Informally, we allow an action to be committed early if we know that
>   the action can occur without assuming some data race occurs.

The big question here is if the last read (read 5) can be reordered so that we could potentially see a non-null wrapper in read 1 and still see a null in the last read. This should not be allowed to happen in the first invocation of `get()` by a thread because then the only way for the last read to occur would be because of a data race and the JMM would prohibit the reordering.

In subsequent invocations of `get()` reordering would be allowed but then it shouldn't matter because wrapper should be visible anyways.

Comment: As an aside: the very fact that this code is subtle and hard to get right should be a sign that this isn't an optimal solution. Prefer something like an [initialization on demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) in real code.

Comment: @DanielPryden I agree, for me it is just a way to evaluate my understanding of multi threading.

Comment: [Does double-checked locking ever work](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is volatile used in this example of double checked locking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855700/why-is-volatile-used-in-this-example-of-double-checked-locking)

Comment: Please see a Related panel to the left. Most questions there are duplicates of this. Answers are not bad too.

Comment: @Basilevs It is possible to do double checked locking without volatile, check the link to Shipilev at the beginning of my question. I'm suggesting a variation on this, also without volatile. So the provided suggestions don't answer my question.