# volatile + synchronized combination in multithreaded scenario

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile

I have good knowledge of `synchronization` internals and basic knowledge of `volatile` internals.

I have one query, which is follow-up to below SE question:

[Why is volatile used in this example of double checked locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855700/why-is-volatile-used-in-this-example-of-double-checked-locking/)

I'm confused about one part. If I strictly follow above example, I have to add `volatile` to many variables but I am sure that all multi-threaded applications are not using this volatile + synchronized combination.

If `synchronization` is not guaranteeing memory consistency as per above example, what are the use cases of using combination of `volatile` variables with `synchronization` code?

Comment: Note: actually using double checked locking for a Singleton is a bad idea because a) Singleton, b) you can use an `enum`

Comment: Definitely I use some other options like enum, Lazy loaders. Just added that question to provide context through some working code. My confusion is only about combination.

Comment: Double checked locking is used for lazy initialization of singleton objects. Also, volatile prevents an optimization that might occur: "This keyword prevents a subtle case where the compiler tries to optimize the code such that that the object is accessed before it is finished being constructed" (OCP Oracle® Certified Professional Java® SE 8 Programmer II)

Comment: The simplest solution for a Singleton if you don't use other static methods or variables on the Singleton is to use an eager solution. An alternative is to use enums, or using the holder class idiom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a variable is defined `volatile` it is read from the main memory instead of registries.

So each processor will see the same value.

In the double check the variable is defined as `volatile` to be sure to check outside of `synchronized` block will intercept most of cases.

If the variable is not `volatile` the code will work, but if you have more processors you can go inside of the `synchronized` block more than needed (also when the variable is not null).

**If all access to a variable are done in the `synchronized` block a `volatile` is not necessary at all.**

Comment: Does your last statement applies to above double locking code too?

Comment: Double check? or double lock?

Comment: It may be typo from OP.  It should be double check.

Comment: Thanks @DavideLorenzoMARINO . Your last statement (If all access to a variable are done in the synchronized block a volatile is not necessary at all.)  has cleared my confusion :)

Comment: >`If all access to a variable are done in the synchronized block a volatile is not necessary at all.` How is that enforced? Volatile is about visibility and synchronized is about making operations atomic. It seems to me like two separate things.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of `volatile` and `synchronized` in that question/answer *only applies* to **double-checked locking**.

If you're not doing double-checked locking, and are accessing your shared variables always within the protection of the same `synchronized` monitor (which is how applications most commonly access shared variables, if they're not using the `java.util.concurrent` classes), then you don't need `volatile`.

In any case, this doesn't mean that double-checked locking is a good idea. Although the `volatile` + `synchronized` construct will make double-checked locking work, it doesn't offer any significant performance benefit, as you can also read in @alf's answer to the question you refer to.

Comment: But in above scenario, the author is using the combination for memory consistency purpose. WIth a single lock condition, above code does not work.

Comment: @AdityaW above code is double-checked locking, and for double-checked locking (in which you access a shared variable outside the `synchronized` block) you need `volatile`. Most multithreaded code is (luckily!) not double-checked locking, as there little or no benefit to it.

Comment: @AdityaW https://gist.github.com/anonymous/52e40d36d7e4caf321630bf71261a7b4 is perfectly fine. The problem in the double checked code arises from unsynchronized & not-volatile access (by a second thread) to the shared (and partially initialized but already visible) variable with 0 memory guarantees.