# confused by synchronized usage

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, synchronized

I see the netflix code, in class DynamicPropertyFactory,there's  a method like

```
public static DynamicPropertyFactory getInstance() {
    if (config == null) {
        synchronized (ConfigurationManager.class) {
            if (config == null) {
                AbstractConfiguration configFromManager = ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance();
                if (configFromManager != null) {
                    initWithConfigurationSource(configFromManager);
                    initializedWithDefaultConfig = !ConfigurationManager.isConfigurationInstalled();
                    logger.info("DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: " + configFromManager);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

I'm confused on this method that why using `synchronized (ConfigurationManager.class)`, key word synchronized  was used on another class `ConfigurationManager.class`. From my view, synchronized is used in its current class. So, someone can help explain this simplely?

Comment: Yes, that's class level synchronization. Please note, the DynamicPropertyFactory is a class method.

Comment: but it's synchronized (ConfigurationManager.class) not synchronized (DynamicPropertyFactory.class),so..

Comment: They only want to initialize class variable config once. During the initialization class method getConfigInstance in class ConfigurationManager is invoked, that's the reason they use class level synchronization (class level lock)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because they expect other classes to access ConfigurationManager on some other thread.

Comment: I guess if a thread invokes method getInstance, and other thread that want to access ConfigurationManager's class or instance method will be blocked, right?

Comment: yes. Although this style seems wierd to me. is this out of curiousity? or are you trying to solve something?

Answer (score 0):

Above code was not well written.

`DynamicPropertyFactory` should not worry about incorporating `synchronized` checks to get  `ConfigurationManager` instance.

Ideally  `ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance()` should have proper checks and   `synchronized (ConfigurationManager.class)` check should be moved to `ConfigurationManager`.

Callers of `ConfigurationManager` should simply get instance with `getConfigInstance()` API without any `synchronized` checks.

Have a look at below SE question to implement Singleton object in right way:

[Why is volatile used in this example of double checked locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855700/why-is-volatile-used-in-this-example-of-double-checked-locking/)