# Why use both local variable and volatile both togather for DCL (as suggested by Sonar tool)?

Tags: java, multithreading, sonarqube, synchronized, double-checked-locking

There are related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855700/why-is-volatile-used-in-double-checked-locking) but they as the focus in those is more on volatile and not much on the usage of local variable, hence I am posting a new question, Please see the question below.

Sonar Source [rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/multi-threading/RSPEC-2168) has a code according to which below code is correct and solves the issues with [DCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)

```
class ResourceFactory {
  private volatile Resource resource;

  public Resource getResource() {
    Resource localResource = resource;
    if (localResource == null) {
      synchronized (this) {
        localResource = resource;
        if (localResource == null) {
          resource = localResource = new Resource();
        }
      }
    }
    return localResource;
  }

  static class Resource {
  }
}
```

I understand that we have alternate options (some better than complicated DCL) like an

1. enum or
2. static inner class holder or
3. a static final reference initialized during its declaration itself.
4. declare the entire method as synchronized.

I wish to understand the usage of volatile along with local variable to resolve the issues for DCL.

Also I understand volatile (for Java 1.5 and later versions) guarantees the  'happens-before' feature which prevents the in-complete object being returned for reading.

**Question 1** I want to understand as what is the need of volatile if a local variable has already been used.  Below code has non volatile variable `resource` but inside the `getResource()` a local variable is used to read the `resource`. Are there still issues in the code ? **(Please see comments in below code below)**

```
class ResourceFactory {
  private Resource resource; // non volatile
  public Resource getResource() {
    Resource localResource = resource; // only 1 read without lock
    if (localResource == null) {
      synchronized (this) {
        localResource = resource; // read inside the synchronized block
        if (localResource == null) {
           localResource = new Resource(); // constructor is initialized. 
           resource = localResource; // ****code reaches here only when constructor has been complete. Here is there a chance of resource being referring to incomplete object ?**** 
        }
      }
    }
    return localResource;
  }

  static class Resource {
  }
}
```

The only advantage I see is with volatile is suppose the object was created then the first read itself would have guaranteed a memory read instead of read from thread cache preventing unnecessary acquisition of lock.

**Question 2** Instead of using local variable if simple volatile was used then was the code without issues ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is volatile used in double checked locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855700/why-is-volatile-used-in-double-checked-locking)

Comment: @j.seashell The other questions I have searched consider the usage of volatile but not local variable as suggested by SONAR. I have mentioned it in the question also, hence requesting not to mark it as duplicate.

Comment: Kindly leave comments along with down-voting so as gaps in the question can be filled

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't understand the downvote reason, the question is legitimate and well researched IMO

Answer (score 2):

Question 2 is directly addressed in *Effective Java*; whilst it may be mentioned in other editions too, the one I have in front of me is *3rd Ed*, Item 83, p335:

> The code may appear a bit convoluted. In particular, the need for the local variable (`result`) may be unclear. What this variable does is to ensure that `field` is read only once in the common case where it's already initialized. While not strictly necessary, this may improve performance and is more elegant by the standards applied to low-level concurrent programming. On my machine, the method above is about 1.4 times as fast as the obvious version without a local variable.

(Note that 3rd Ed has a serious error in the code sample for double-checked locking (immediately preceding this quote) in early printings! Check out the errata for corrected code.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for my confusions but it will be really helpful if you could correct my understanding. 1. local variable : My understanding it is the local variable which is made to refer the object and its always different local variable for each thread (on its stack). localVariable = new Instance(); once this line is executed and control moves to next statement i.e. instanceVaribale = localVariable; by this time constructor execution is over and hence always instanceVatiable sees a complete object. Please correct me if I am wrong. Then I have 1 more doubt which I will post